# Is there simple drupal 7 cart modules?

Tags: 7

I really need to create a cart system without payment methods , I only want to get an order email from the user. Is there any modules in drupal 7 to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Webform module](https://drupal.org/project/webform) is sufficient in your case?

With Webform you can create forms and form components from an UI. When a submission has been made from a user you can setup mails that should be sent.

Comment: OP specifically mention about cart system not only the contact

Comment: Well that depends how you define a cart system. Who says the Webform module only can be used for contact forms? Why not use it as a webshop?